# MySQL SELECT clause means for WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I can't figure out what `p2` means in the below `SELECT` clause. Can anyone explain to me what that means?

```
SELECT id
FROM wp_posts p2
WHERE p2.post_status = 'publish'
    AND p2.post_author = wp_posts.post_author
ORDER BY p2.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just an alias for the table right before the first time it's used (`wp_posts`, in this example). It's totally unnecessary in the example you posted.

Answer (score 2):

your query creates Alias for table WP_Posts

```
SELECT id FROM wp_posts p2
```

P2 is your table wp_posts